# Power BI. Drill down on pie chart by filtering

Tags: powerbi

I have a pie chart which shows the distribution of groups, and when I drill down on it, it will show the distribution of departments by selected group. I also have a slicer to filter the pie chart by groups.

[image: Distribution of groups]
[image: Distribution of departments by selected group]

[image: Slicer to filter the pie charts]

I want to be able to drill down to the second level. Basically getting to the second image by using the slicer. Is it possible in Power BI, or do I need custom visuals?

Comment: Is it correct that you want all this out of a single visual?  So you have your pie chart at the Group level, and you'd like to filter AND drill down by clicking on the slicer?  Or is it ok to have two visuals?

Comment: Yes I need it to be in a single visual and drill down by clicking on the slicer. Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with any way to cause a drill-down operation based on changing a slicer setting.  I would do this by having a chart that already exists at the department level and filtering it by group in the slicer.  But you won't get the relationship between groups without another visual so it's not a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have a 'hack' for you to consider.

1) Create two pie charts, one for group and one for department

2) Add a row to your dataset 
Group:"_All" | Department:"_All"

3) Modify your interactions so that chances to the slicer don't filter the 'Groups' pie chart

4) Add a filter to both of the pie charts to exclude group _All

5) Drag the Department pie *exactly* on top of the Group pie.

When you have _All selected in the slicer, that will collide with the filters in your departments pie, it won't show anything at all, and the 'Groups' pie will be visible underneath.  Otherwise, filtering for any of the other groups will cause the Departments pie to show on top, filtered properly.

There's a lot of drawbacks.  Data labels, differences in size, titles -- all that stuff has to be turned off because they cause overlapping and it looks horrible.  Mouseover is a little weird, and all cross filtering / highlighting from other visuals has to be considered and managed.

But, in the golden path, it will at least look like it's supposed look.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to work well as long as I don't mouseover the visuals like you said.